# ¿Existe algún método de la clase java que me permita saber si una clase se ha instanciado ya anteriormente?

Tags: java, objeto

Tengo una clase que se ejecuta n veces cada vez que realizo una acción, la idea es que solo se ejecute una vez, y para posteriores llamadas a esa clase, utilizar la ya instanciada, no otra nueva.

Quiero controlarlo con un if, pero necesito algún método para ver si ya ha sido instanciada (Si lo hay).

Comment: Investiga qué es y como crear un singleton. Es un patrón de diseño.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A veces lo que queremos no siempre es lo que necesitamos, pero si, es posible.

La clase en cuestion es `java.lang.ClassLoader`, que es la clase que se encarga de cargar en memoria en todas las situaciones posibles. El metodo que usa internamente es `findLoadedClass`, pero debido a que es de visibilidad `protected` no lo puedes usar directamente a menos.... que hagas tu propio classloader y hagas una version en la que agregues una version publica de [findLoadedClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findLoadedClass(java.lang.String)).

Ahora en la practica realmente no necesitas saber si ya se instancio, solamente necesitas usar una instancia y para ello hay un anti-design pattern llamado singleton.

La forma mas elemental de aplicarlo es la siguiente:

```
class MiClase{

 private static MiClase instancia;

 private MiClase(){ // constructor privado para que solo pueda ser llamado internamente
 }
 public static String saluda(){
  if(instancia == null){
   instancia = new MiClase(); // como el constructor es privado evitamos errores
  }
  return instancia.getSaludoDesdeInternet();
 }

 public String getSaludoDesdeInternet(){
  // implementacion
 }
}
```

Con ese simple if nos aseguramos de que no haya nulos. Donde podriamos tener problemas es en el caso de que llamaramos a nuestro metodo en paralelo, ya que se podrian crear mas de una instancia, tampoco serian demasiadas, pero el tiempo en que se guarda algo en memoria es mas rapido del tiempo en que se lee para verificar si ya existe, asi que en lo que escribes tu primera instancia otra u otras se pueden crear porque el if no para la ejecucion.
Basicamente mientras no uses hilos no tienes nada de que preocuparte.